# Child theme creates a duplicate instance

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I created a child theme for WordPress and then called one of the parent themes files in the child theme's `functions.php` tile with `include('functions/breadcrumb.php');`

That crashed the site with a 500 error. Is there a way to declare a single instance or include in the child theme so that the parent then doesn't attempt to load the `breadcrumb.php` file?

Thanks

Comment: Does the breadcrumbs.php file load in the child theme without adding the extra include? Child themes load everything the parent theme loads, plus the child theme files, so you shouldn't need to re-load it if its loaded by the parent theme already.

Comment: If you are trying to replace a function in your parent theme, you can only do that if the parent theme's functions are pluggable, that is, wrapped in a `function_exists()` if statement. If they are, any child theme function will override the the parent theme function baring the same name.

Comment: @DACrosby I need to load the breadcrumbs.php file in the child theme because that file contains the code I need to customize.

Comment: @YoavKadosh  To make sure I understand, the parent theme's header.php file calls mytheme_breadcrumb function which is then in the functions/breadcrumb.php file. So I need to look to see if mytheme_breadcrumb is wrapped in 'function_exists ()' within the parent theme's header.php?

Comment: Here is the code that calls the function within the header.php 

`<?php if(!is_404() && !is_page_template('comming-soon.php') ) {
 if (function_exists('converio_breadcrumb')) {
  converio_breadcrumb();
 } 
} ?>`

Comment: @WPMonkey that is correct. However, according to your code, I cannot determine whether `converio_breadcrumb` is pluggable or not, since the function **declaration** needs to be wrapped, not a function call (which is the case in the code you've provided). You need to look for the function's declaration in the theme files. If it is wrapped in a `function_exists` statement, then it is pluggable.

Comment: Yes, thank you @YoavKadosh, the function declaration was not wrapped. I had to call a unique breadcrumb2.php. Thank you for your help